# My usestate is not getting updated even though I set it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm printing the `stream` variable, but I am getting `null` even after I update it.

Should I re-render the whole component when my set state is called? Since this code executes once if so, how to do it?

```js
const [stream, setStream] = useState(null);

async function getLocalStream() {
  let isFront = true;

  const devices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  if (!stream) {
    let s;
    try {
      s = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      });
      setStream(s); //here i am setting my state
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  socket.current = io.connect('http://192.8.1.13:3001');
  socket.current.emit('new-room', route.params.roomid, route.params.name);

  socket.current.on('room-created', async (id, roomid, name) => {
    getLocalStream(); // calling function
  });

  socket.current.on('join-room', async (id, roomid, name) => {
    getLocalStream();
  });

  socket.current.on('new-user', async (id, roomid, name) => {
    console.log('stream', stream); // my value is always null
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: You don't need to manually trigger a rerender as `setState` will trigger one for you. At a quick glance, I think the issue is caused by a race condition between the `setState` call and the console.log. Perhaps you can use another `useEffect` with the `stream` state as a dependency and try console.log it there.

Comment: ok will try and let you know @Moistbobo